# Enzyme unit test is passing test when it should fail

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a component it has two props title, and url.

I'm unsure how to pass mock data, i made an attempt but it passes but im pretty sure its not reading whats in the data `object`

Both tests are passing.

**Card.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
const Styles = {
    width: '300px',
    height: '300px'
}
class Card extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {/* Renders title of the GIY  */}
                <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
                <div >
                    <img alt="" src={this.props.url}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Card;
```

**Card.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import Card from './Card';

describe('Should render Card Component', ()=> {
    it('should render card component', ()=> {
      const component = shallow(<Card />);

    })

});

describe('Should render title/ url prop', ()=>{
    it('should render title /url prop', ()=>{
        // trying to mock data for the Card component
        const data = {
            title: "owl",
            url:"https://giphy.com/gifs/bird-owl-qISaMW1xwmvNS"
        }

        const component = shallow(<Card title={data.title} url={data.url}/>)

    })
})
```

Comment: How would your test fail, it has no `expect()`ations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're not making any assertions**. You need to `expect` some result to happen.

**Card.js** (this can be a pure function if it doesn't require `state`)

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const styles = {
  width: "300px",
  height: "300px"
};

const Card = ({ title, url }) =>
  title && url ? ( // if a title and url are passed in, return <div>...</div>, else return "null"
    <div className="card">
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <div>
        <img alt="" src={url} styles={styles} />
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : null;

// PropTypes will throw a warning if either of them is missing
PropTypes.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  url: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default Card;
```

**Card.test.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Card from "../index";

// we define initial props (empty strings)
const initialProps = {
  title: "",
  url: ""
};

// we shallow wrap the Card while passing in the "initialProps" 
const wrapper = shallow(<Card {...initialProps} />);

// we define some props that will be passed in during our second test
const nextProps = {
  title: "owl",
  url: "https://media.giphy.com/media/qISaMW1xwmvNS/giphy.gif"
};

describe("Card Component", () => {
  afterAll(() => wrapper.unmount());

  it("shouldn't render a card without the required props", () => {
    expect(wrapper.type()).toBeNull();
  });

  it("should render a card if the required props are present", () => {
    wrapper.setProps({ ...nextProps }); // we update the component with "nextProps"

    expect(wrapper.find("div.card")).toHaveLength(1); // expect "div.card" to be present
    expect(wrapper.find("h1").text()).toContain(nextProps.title); // expect the "h1" element to contain "owl"
    expect(wrapper.find("img").prop("src")).toBe(nextProps.url); // expect the "img"'s src to be "https://media.giphy.com/media/qISaMW1xwmvNS/giphy.gif"
  });
});
```

**Working example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/k35zpqwk97